# How do I file a complaint about a bank's dishonest practices to Visa/Mastercard?

Tags: credit-card

How do I file a complaint about a bank's dishonest practices to Visa or Mastercard?

Comment: Can you provide any more details? Else, the best one might do for you is "here's the contact info...."

Comment: If the bank's practices are really "dishonest", you should be contacting banking authorities with copy to the bank's CEO or vice versa.

Comment: I contacted local banking authorities. I also want to report them to their card providers/partners (visa and mastercard). I'm pretty sure they have to follow some rules set by visa/mc, no?

Comment: @xqwxeqwex Yes, but the rules don't always cover or require what you would think they should.  As the first comment says, if you provide details, someone may be able to tell you whether it's actually prohibited, or just unethical-but-permitted.

Comment: So there's no way to complain to MC/V?

Comment: What do you want to complain about? The relationship between banks and credit networks is contractual.

Comment: So there's no way to complain to MC/V about their partner bank?

Comment: Sure there is. Find the company's mailing address and send them a letter. Be sure to explain exactly what the issue is and why they should care about it, ideally including a pointer to exactly what policy is being violated. Don't expect much satisfaction .

Comment: The point is that you're not a party to their contract, so what exactly are you going to complain about and why? MC/V have no obligation to you.

Comment: @xqwxeqwex If you don't want to tell us, you're welcome to [read Visa's rules](https://usa.visa.com/content/dam/VCOM/download/about-visa/visa-rules-public.pdf) yourself and see if you can find something that prohibits whatever you experienced.  Mastercard has a similar document you can search for if you'd like.

Answer (score 4):

As a general rule, you don't.

Visa [sets the rules](https://usa.visa.com/content/dam/VCOM/download/about-visa/visa-rules-public.pdf) by which banks can issue cards with the Visa logo on them and the rules about how merchants can charge cards with that logo.  It has no relationship to the consumer, and my understanding is that if you do manage to reach them, they're just going to forward your complaint (whatever it is) to your issuing bank to resolve.  MasterCard has slightly different rules, but they're basically the same as far as the cardholder is concerned.

If you look at Visa's [official FAQ page](https://usa.visa.com/support/consumer/visa-rules.html), you'll see that the only options they give you are to report a problem with a *merchant* (not a bank) or to ask questions about the rules.  All the FAQ entries are likewise about consumer-merchant or merchant-Visa issues - nothing about the actual issuing banks.

The proper avenue for reporting issues with a bank is your local banking authority, as @keshlam mentioned in the comments.  There's no method to go over the bank's head and report them to the card brands.